# How to get a maximum of 3D matrix based on the first element in python

Tags: python, max, 3dsmax

I have a 3D matrix with the shape of `(3,2,2)`. Like this:

```
t[0]=[2,4
      5,6]    

t[1]=[3,3
      2,3]

t[2]=[1,5
     4,7]
```

I want to get   a maximum of `t` to give me `6`, `3`, and `7` that `6` is the max of `t[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: You can loop through the array and take the maximum value for each sub array:

```
[np.max(x) for x in t]
# [6, 3, 7]
```

Anther option:

```
t.reshape(3,4).max(axis = 1)
# array([6, 3, 7]
```

A simpler method is:

```
t.max(axis = (1,2))
# array([6, 3, 7])
```

---

Some bench mark about the above three methods:

```
%timeit [np.max(x) for x in t]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 µs per loop

%timeit t.reshape(3,4).max(axis = 1)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.75 µs per loop

%timeit t.max(axis = (1,2))
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.63 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is it the fastest way?

Comment: Which of them is the fastest?

Comment: See the time testing above. The native numpy solution should be faster.